# Android GCM not send notification message to device

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have facing problem in getting notification message from GCM Server.Device will get notification correctly when it not idle or in running state but when device goes idle for 10-15 minutes at that time device not able to get notification and also all registered devices are not gets notification from GCM server.How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, your app need to wake when it sleeps.

1. Put this into your manifest file to wake your device when the message is received

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
   ```
2. Add java class name WakeLocker.java

   ```
   public abstract class WakeLocker {
   private static PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

   public static void acquire(Context context) {
       if (wakeLock != null) wakeLock.release();

       PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
       wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |
           PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |
           PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "WakeLock");
       wakeLock.acquire();
       }

       public static void release() {
           if (wakeLock != null) wakeLock.release(); wakeLock = null;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Call the above code in 'private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()' that might be in your MainActivity.java

   ```
     private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
       // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
       WakeLocker.acquire(getApplicationContext());

       /**
        * Take appropriate action on this message
        * depending upon your app requirement
        * For now i am just displaying it on the screen
        * */

       // Showing received message
       lblMessage.append(newMessage + "\n");           
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Message: " + newMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       // Releasing wake lock
       WakeLocker.release();
   }
   };
   ```

   Thank [This source](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

   Hope this helps